# Is there any way to replace gatling's execution time with my server execution time in report (html) file?

Tags: karate

I want to view Gatling html report based on my server execution time. I have a few apis which return execution time in their response body. I would like to use that execution time in Gatling report, not the Gatling's execution time.
[image]
Therefore, I want to generate Gatling's report based on my execution time. Can anyone please let me know the process?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not supported. But you are welcome to contribute code to do it.